# Please explain this Python .format call

Tags: python, syntax

I am porting a Sonos controller written in Python to another language. I'm struggling to understand what this method call is doing:

```
 def __send_command(self, endpoint, action, body):
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
            'SOAPACTION': action
        }

        soap = SOAP_TEMPLATE.format(body=body)
```

Specifically the .format method.  As far as I can tell, soap, SOAP_TEMPLATE and body are all strings.

Where:

```
SOAP_TEMPLATE = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body>{body}</s:Body></s:Envelope>'
```

and

```
body = '<u:GetPositionInfo xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID><Channel>Master</Channel></u:GetPositionInfo>'
```

Could somebody please explain in plain English what the `.format` method is doing?

Comment: Have you tried looking it up? http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: I have read the documentation but I didn't understand it. Hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting). Which is a way to format strings. (Prepare them, put them together)

Example:

```
>>> "hello {name}".format(name="garry")
'hello garry'
```

Or, a better example:

```
>>> for name in ["garry", "inbar"]:
    print "hello {name}".format(name=name)


hello garry
hello inbar
```

---

In your case, probably the `SOAP_TEMPLATE` is a string which contains a `{body}` tag in it, and this function takes it and adds the `body` passed to the function into that string.

Answer (score 3):

[`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) interpolates values into a string and lets you set the formatting for those values.

Your string contains the simple placeholder `{body}` and that is replaced by the value passed in as a keyword `.format(body=body)`.

The short-short version of your template is:

```
>>> 'Hello {body}!'.format(body='World!')
'Hello World!!'
```

See [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) for the nitty-gritty details of how `{}` template slots let you specify what values to interpolate, and [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) on how you can alter how values are formatted.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct: this is about strings formatting.

Your example is roughly equivalent to this:

```
def __send_command(self, endpoint, action, body):
    # ... some code here ...
    soap = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body>' + body + '</s:Body></s:Envelope>'
    # ... some code here ...
```

**Disclaimer**: The code is not *pythonic*, it may also break if `body` is not of `str` type. The only reason I built it is to show something that could resemble different language more (assuming that language has similar notation for concatenating strings).